# Есть ли возможность указать для делегата несколько типов возврата?

Tags: c#

Так чтобы например в такой ситуации заменить `object` на `int|double|string`: первый и второй примеры кода.

```
    private Dictionary<string, Func<int[], object>> Funcs2 = new Dictionary<string, Func<int[], object>>{
        {"min2sum", (nums) => nums.OrderBy(n => n).Take(2).Sum()},
        {"max3average", (nums) => nums.OrderByDescending(n => n).Take(3).Average()},
        {"arrToString", (nums) => nums.ToString()}
        };
```

```
    private Dictionary<string, Func<int[], int|double|string>> Funcs2 = new Dictionary<string, Func<int[], int|double|string>>{};
```

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Вы хотите универсальный метод? Если да, то вам нужны generic (обобщения), где вы будете указывать тип при вызове (`T SomeMethod<T>()` ... `int result = SomeMethod<int>()`). Если вы хотите возвращать сразу несколько значений, то лучше сделайте класс и заполняйте его, ну или на крайний случай кортежи (`(int, double, string)` ... `return (1, 2, "3")`). Судя кстати по коду, вы нарушаете SRP, то есть ваш код выполняет сразу несколько задач, что не очень хорошо в плане построения архитектуры проекта, разбейте на мелкие части все это, не лепите в одну кучу!

Comment: Нет, каждая функция возвращает 1 значение 1 типа.

    public Numbers(string func, int[] nums)
    {
        Result = Funcs[func](nums);
    }

Comment: Про SRP спасибо, но это же не религия.

Comment: @pontekorvo, нет это не религия, просто инструкция как не хлестать себя серпом по яйцам, чем вы и занимаетесь. Что подтверждается наличие этого вопроса, нагородив вы в тупике что делать, даже читать кусок этого кодо больно. Ваш подход к решению задачи мягко говоря недопустим.

Comment: А тут дело не в религии, тут дело в удобстве и дальнейшем расширении. Когда у вас все намешено в одну кучу, то через некое время начнете в прямом смысле слова страдать, ибо чтоб изменить один участок кода, вам надо переписать пол проекта. Для этого и придумывают всякие подходы и наборы рекомендаций. В хорошем проекте вы без труда должны уметь добавить новый функционал, полностью не затрагивая старый.

Comment: А что, если бы это был не C#, а PHP?

Comment: Например с таким массивом: 

    $funcs = [
        'object' => fn () => "complex value",
        'boolean' => fn ($value) => json_encode($value)
    ];

$type = gettype($value);

return $funcs[$type]($value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятен контекст того, что вы хотите сделать.
Если прямо отвечать, то нет, нельзя так указать.
Из существующих инструментов вы можете использовать object, но с ним могут быть проблемы при проверке содержащегося типа.
Ещё вариант - вы можете возвращать кортеж `(int? intval, double? dval, string strval)`
Пример: `Func<int[], (int? intval, double? dval, string strval)>`

Ещё лучше, если вы опишите свой класс/структуру с 3мя полями нужных вам типов данных и enum-полем, указывающим на то, какой тип сейчас используется, например:

```
//совершенно без проблем может быть и структурой  
class MyDataContainerIntDoubleString
{
    public CurrentDataTypeIntDoubleString CurrentDataType { get; set; } = CurrentDataTypeIntDoubleString.Undefined;
    public int IntVal { get; set; }
    public double DoubleVal { get; set; }
    public string StringVal { get; set; }

    public enum CurrentDataTypeIntDoubleString
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Int = 1,
        Double = 2,
        String = 3
    }
}
```

... и будуте передавать его, например: `Func<int[], MyDataContainerIntDoubleString>`